# PyQt5 QWidget not filling parent

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm creating a code editor in PyQt5. I'm using a QGridLayout in the center widget and building the UI from there. The problem I'm facing is that the QPlainTextEdit's and the Menu don't fill the available space on the center widget. I tried setting the size policy to expanding and tried adapting the stretch parameters of the QGridLayout.

I'm running the code in python 2.7 and PyQt 5. Using the PyCharm IDE.

Main.py

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QAction

from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

import UI

versao = '3.0.0'


class Principal(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Principal, self).__init__()

        self.acao_novo = 0
        self.acao_abrir = 0
        self.acao_exemplos = 0
        self.acao_sair = 0
        self.acao_salvar = 0
        self.acao_salvar_como = 0
        self.acao_comentar_linha = 0
        self.acao_achar = 0
        self.acao_achar_e_substituir = 0
        self.acao_ir_para_linha = 0
        self.acao_placa = 0
        self.acao_porta = 0
        self.acao_lingua = 0
        self.acao_monitor_serial = 0
        self.acao_verificar = 0
        self.acao_verificar_e_carregar = 0

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.setCentralWidget(UI.Centro())

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 550)
        self.setWindowTitle('Br.ino ' + versao)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(os.path.join('recursos', 'logo.png')))
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    principal = Principal()
    app.setStyleSheet("""QMainWindow {
                             background: '#252525';
                         }
                         QMenu{
                             background: '#252525';
                         }
                         QMenu::item {
                             background: '#252525';
                         } 
                         QMenu::item:selected{
                             background: '#101010';
                         }
                         QMenuBar {
                             background: '#252525';
                         }
                         QMenuBar::item {
                             background: '#252525';
                         } 
                         QMenuBar::item:selected{
                             background: '#101010';
                         }
                         QPlainTextEdit{
                             background: '#252525';
                             border: None;
                             border-radius: 6px;
                             color: '#efefef';
                             selection-background-color: '#454545';
                         }""")
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

UI.py

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QGridLayout, QPlainTextEdit, QVBoxLayout, QSpacerItem, QSizePolicy, QAbstractButton)
import os
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize


class Centro(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Centro, self).__init__()
        self.layout = 0

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.setRowStretch(0, 7.5)
        layout.setRowStretch(1, 2.5)
        layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        layout.setColumnStretch(1, 5)
        menu = Menu.Menu()
        layout.addWidget(menu, 0, 0, 1, 0)
        layout.setSpacing(10)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        container = QWidget(self)
        container.setStyleSheet("background:#252525")
        editor = QPlainTextEdit(container)
        layout.addWidget(container, 0, 1, 9, 9)

        container_log = QWidget(self)
        log = QPlainTextEdit(container_log)
        log.setStyleSheet("background:#000000")
        log.setDisabled(True)
        layout.addWidget(container_log, 1, 1, 1, 8)

        self.show()


class Menu(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Menu, self).__init__()
        self.layout = 0

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        container = QWidget(self)
        container.setFixedWidth(60)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(container)
        container.setStyleSheet("background-color: '#5cb50d';")

        btn_compilar = botaoImagem(QPixmap(os.path.join('recursos', 'compilarFoco.png')), self)
        btn_compilar_e_carregar = botaoImagem(QPixmap(os.path.join('recursos', 'carregarFoco.png')), self)
        btn_novo = botaoImagem(QPixmap(os.path.join('recursos', 'novoArquivoFoco.png')), self)
        btn_abrir = botaoImagem(QPixmap(os.path.join('recursos', 'abrirPastaFoco.png')), self)
        btn_salvar = botaoImagem(QPixmap(os.path.join('recursos', 'salvarFoco.png')), self)
        btn_monitor_serial = botaoImagem(QPixmap(os.path.join('recursos', 'monitorSerialFoco.png')), self)
        btn_monitor_serial.setFixedSize(50, 50)

        layout.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 0)
        espacador_vertical = QSpacerItem(0, 500000000, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        layout.addWidget(btn_compilar)
        layout.addWidget(btn_compilar_e_carregar)
        layout.addWidget(btn_novo)
        layout.addWidget(btn_abrir)
        layout.addWidget(btn_salvar)
        layout.addWidget(btn_monitor_serial)
        layout.addItem(espacador_vertical)

        self.show()


class botaoImagem(QAbstractButton):
    def __init__(self, pixmap, parent=None):
        super(botaoImagem, self).__init__(parent)
        self.pixmap = pixmap

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(event.rect(), self.pixmap)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(50, 63)
```

The expected result is as follow(this screenshot is a previous version, developed in Java, thus it includes a few features not implemented yet):[image: Screenshot]

Comment: what is `Menu.Menu()`?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but... `layout.addWidget(menu, 0, 0, 1, 0)` specifies that `menu` should span *zero* columns.

Comment: Could you show a picture of what you want to get?

Comment: Menu is a class, Menu.Menu() is the constructor. 
Actually menu occupies the column 0
I'll add a picture ASAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create "container" widgets, they aren't needed. Add the widgets directly to your layouts.

Your problem is that although you are setting up layouts, you are adding the container widgets to the parent *without* a layout, and thus the *container* won't scale.

i.e unstead of

```
container = QWidget(self)
container.setStyleSheet("background:#252525")
editor = QPlainTextEdit(container)
layout.addWidget(container, 0, 1, 9, 9)
```

write

```
editor = QPlainTextEdit(self)
editor.setStyleSheet("background:#252525")
layout.addWidget(editor, 0, 1, 9, 9)
```

***Update:*** Here's how to do it for `Menu`

```
layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
self.setFixedWidth(60)
self.setStyleSheet("background-color: '#5cb50d';")
```

Comment: How should I do it with the Menu class? How to add parent to __init__?

Comment: Works for the horizontal expansion, however, the menu won't expand vertically

Comment: See my updated answer. If you've added it to the layout correctly it should expand vertically. If your intended behaviour is for the buttons to expand to fill the available space then you'll want to remove the `QSpacerItem` in `Menu`. Also make sure you've addressed the issue pointed out above by @G.M.